# Need an example showing that default constructor is not inherited

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, default-constructor, inherited-constructors

I know that default constructor is not inherited, as stated in [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

And there is an example there:

```c++
struct B2 {
  B2(int = 13, int = 42);
};

struct D2 : B2 {
  using B2::B2;
};
```

With quite good explanation:

> The candidate set of inherited constructors in `D2` for `B2` is
>
> ```c++
> ...
> —B2(int = 13, int = 42)
> —B2(int = 13)
> —B2()
> ```

And most important:

> The set of constructors present in `D2` is
> `—D2()`, implicitly-declared default constructor, not inherited

For me this example does not show the difference, in a sense that even if this very constructor was inherited - its behavior was not different from the implicitly-declared default constructor.

I need an example showing the difference in the way that can be easily understand for, let say, an audience familiar with C++03 but wanting to learn C++11.

---

**[UPDATE]**
All answers (including my own) are of kind "*if default c-tor was inherited then the example would compile/not compile*".

I'd prefer answers where the outcome (observable behavior) is different than it would be otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
struct foo
{
    foo() {}
    foo(int) {}
};

struct bar : foo
{
    using foo::foo;
};

int main()
{
    bar b;
}
```

This compiles: Since `bar` has no *user-declared* constructors, a default constructor will be declared implicitly.

```
struct foo
{
    foo() {}
    foo(int) {}
};

struct bar : foo
{
    using foo::foo;
    bar(double) {}
};

int main()
{
    bar b;
}
```

This does not compile. The default constructor is not inherited, and it is not declared implicitly, since there is the `bar(double)` constructor.

Comment: Looking at the proposals (e.g. [N2203](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2007/n2203.html)), this seems to have been (part of?) the rationale not to inherit copy/move and default ctors.

Answer (score 3):

One possible difference: multiple-constructor-inheritance from classes with default constructors. For example:

```
struct A { A(int=0); };
struct B { B(double=3.14); };
struct C : A, B {
  using A::A;
  using B::B;
};

C c;
```

If default constructors were inherited, `C` would inherit one from both `A` and `B`, resulting in ambiguity.

I can't think of a use case for multiple-constructor-inheritance, so this may not be the perfect example you're looking for, but it's something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example, that can be produced from the following feature of inherited constructors:

> 12.9 Inheriting constructors
>  
>   [...] 
>   4) A constructor so declared has the same access as the corresponding constructor in X.

So my proposal is to have protected default constructor in base:

```
class Base {
protected:
    Base(int) {}
    Base() = default;
};
```

If this constructor was derived, then derived class cannot be instantiated because derived constructor would have protected access. If not derived - then default implicitly declared constructor has public access:

```
struct Derived : Base {
    using Base::Base;
};

int main() {
    Derived d1{};  // not inherited, default constructor is public
    Derived d2{1}; // not compiling since this c-tor is inherited, thus protected
}
```