# Cannot create subclass from implicit inherited superclass constructor c++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

I have a class `Scalable`:

```
template<typename T, int size>
class Scalable {
// implementation
protected:
    std::array<T, size> data;
}
```

and a derived class `Color`:

```
struct Color : Scalable<double, 3> {
// implementation
}
```

When I try to do something like

```
Scalable<double, 3> s;
Color c(s);
```

I get

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'Color'
```

I have not defined any of the functions in the rule of 5, but I thought since `Color` is a `Scalable` it could use the implicitly defined copy constructor.

Does this mean for every subclass I have to define the constructor

```
Subclass(const Scalable<T, n> & o)
```

even though there are no extra fields?

I also tried adding `using Scalable<double, 3>::Scalable;` but that didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450803/copy-constructor-is-not-inherited